# how to extract specific name from folder or file name

Tags: linux, awk, csh

I'm new to linux command.

Now I would like to extract only date value from listed file name and compare as a date value.

Example:
/underdirectory

20080206
20080207
**bk_20080208**

I want to listed all above directories and compare date, means this directory is greater or smaller than which is according to specified date.
If all of the listed directories will be date, it's ok for condition check.

## code

foreach date_directory ( `ls` )
if ( "$date_directory" >= "$fdate" && "$date_directory" <= "$tdate") then 
echo ${target_del}${date_directory} >> ${output} 
endif 
end

But if include some words such as "bk_20080228" or "bk_20080228_bk" or "20080228_bk" or "20080228_tt", there condition check will be error.

**bk_20080208**  want to take only 20080208.

please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: So, your input is a file containing 1 line with 3 fields and you want a tool to output just the last field with `bk_` removed from it, right? If you want something else, update your question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear points. I mean there's folder list under parent folder. (eg. test1folder has 3 folders like my post.). So i'd like to only extract 20080208.

Comment: There are no folders in UNIX, there are directories and files. Let's assume you have a directory within which are 3 files. Are you saying you want to find the files under that directory whose names start with a `-bk_` and print the subsequent digits from that file name but ignore all the other file names? If not, again - please update your question to clarify. Also, if your file names don't really start with `-`s then don't put `-`s in front of them in your posted sample input.

Comment: I'm already modified my post. plz check it. sorry for my unclear points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use grep regexp  `grep -Eo '[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}'` or `grep -Eo '[0-9]+'`

Comment: Why not replace '[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}` with `[0-9]{8}`?

Comment: Can be replaced. I have extract the year, month and day

Answer (score 0):

```
   shopt -s nullglob
   for i in *;do echo $i|sed 's/.*_//';done
```

the output can be redirected as per needs.